# How to get list of the dynamic dropdown/selectbox field in javascript and laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel 5.2 and I have an update form modal/popup which has a dynamic dropdown field that can add more or remove it. My problem is the dropdown list in only worked in the first row, after I added more dropdown, it does not show the list in it, because I do not know how to put foreach in the javascript.
This below is a code in the blade view. The second one is the code in the javascript to add more row / dropdown. Do you know how?

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
    <tbody id="tbodpengikut">
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="id_add_pengikut" name="id_add_pengikut[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">
                    <option value=""> --Silahkan Pilih-- </option>
                    @foreach($getPengikut as $getPngkt) 
                        <option value="{{ $getPngkt->KODE }}"> {{ $getPngkt->DESKRIPSI }} </option> 
                    @endforeach
                </select>   
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><b>+</b></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the javascript:

```
var i=1;  
$('#add').click(function(){  
    i++;  
    $('#dynamic_field').append(
       '<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added">
           <td>
                <select class="form-control" id="add_pengikut_id" name="add_pengikut_id" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%"> 
                    <option value=""> --Silahkan Pilih-- </option> 
                </select>
           </td>
           <td>
                <button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button>
           </td>
       </tr>'
    );  
});
```

Comment: Well, for one, adding 'more of' means you have to switch from `id` to `class`, or enumerate *every* duplicate `id` so they are *unique*.

Comment: The portion of the above said also goes for the `name` attribute, you gotta enumerate every `name` attribute differently.

Answer (score 0):

first make **add** class of buttons not id

```
<button type="button" name="add"  class="add btn btn-success"><b>+</b></button>
```

Then your javascript would be like

```
$('table#dynamic_field').on('click','button.add', function (e) {

   var newRow =  $(this).parent().parent().clone();

   $('table#dynamic_field tbody').append(newRow);

});
```